# Printing a book in word - double sided, multiple pages on one sheet

Tags: book, printing, microsoft-word

I want to print a mini book, of about 8 pages, one one sheet. It should be something along the lines of [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Pocketmods-little-booklets-with-MS-Word/), which I have tried. But this is not double sided, so when you are done, you see blank sides in between each page. I have a double sided printer and figure there must be a way to do this so each page is printed front and back. Any templates or instructions?

Comment: Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, I have 10 and 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating my own template using text boxes in Word.

Like this:
2,5 upside down.
1,6 right side up.

Next page 4,3 upside down.
back, cover right side up.

Printed back to back.

In the end, I preferred the look of the original link, despite it being smaller and having blank backs.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this a lot to print out drafts.  I have 2 methods but prefer the 2nd:

1. In word, Layout > Page Setup (small icon bottom right of ribbon box) > Margins > Pages section > Book fold.  Then when I print I'll use landscape and select "print on both sides".
2. In word, save as pdf, then print > booklet (print on both sides selected).

I have an epson printer and both of these methods work okay.  If the double sided print still doesn't print, and the "print preview" looks good, it might be a printer settings problem.   The links online will be [how to print a booklet](https://word.tips.net/T003927_Booklet_Printing_in_Word.html) (or book fold) in word.  However double sided printer problems will depend on the make of the printer.

Alternatively, when I want to print an 8 page booklet on 1 sheet I print double sided on a4 with the text in a6 and use a guillotine. That way each page takes up a quarter of the a4 and the booklet can be formed by cutting the a4 in half portrait. If printing pdf I would use "Multiple", pages per sheet, 2x2, page order horizontal and check print on both sides. If printing from word I would use the dropdown 4 pages per sheet at the bottom of the print dialogue.

If you are lucky enough to have access to adobe indesign, there is also a file>print booklet 2-up perfect bound option that works like a charm.

Comment: I don't understand how you can make an 8 page book on one sheet using either of your methods. Can you be more specific, as if you were making it yourself?

Comment: When I want to print an 8 page booklet on 1 sheet I print double sided on a4 with the text in a6 and use a guillotine.  That way each page takes up a quarter of the a4 and the booklet can be formed by cutting the a4 in half portrait.  If printing pdf I would use "Multiple", pages per sheet, 2x2, page order horizontal and check print on both sides.  If printing from word I would use the dropdown 4 pages per sheet at the bottom of the print dialogue.

Comment: @ArianeKhAnderson please add this comment to your answer, it is WELL worth an upvote with it

Comment: Thanks, and @user2430018, how is it coming along?  I also had issues with pages being upside down, or the signatures printing in the wrong order.  Is there any more errors? This is quite useful: http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sgrais/bookbinding.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have a manual process

1 first print the odd pages >>>>> you must select reverse print in this step

2 after the printer finishes its task you should hold the printed pages and reverse them clockwise 180

3 untick the reverse print and print all the even pages